# Why do these two apis for the same site not have the same methods?

Tags: java, junit, javadoc, assert

I'am checking out apis for the Assert class and found two for that class.(http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/Assert.html and
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)
Is there a reason that these two do not have the same methods?
The first one had a assertequals(int a, int b) I was able to call but the second one didn't have that method. I was confused because they are both from the same site and seem to be about the same class.

Comment: The former one is the javadoc for JUnit 3.8, and the latter is JUnit 4.

Comment: is there a way to tell that the second one belongs to JUnit 4? Nothing in the url says that

Comment: JUnit 4 uses the package name `org.junit.*` while JUnit 3 uses `junit.framework.*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one belongs to JUnit 3 (which is obsolete). The second one belongs to JUnit 4 (the current version).
Use JUnit 4, and never use the first one. You can use [this method](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28long,%20long%29) to check the equality of two integers. They will automatically be promoted to long.

Comment: how did you get to that method from the JUnit 4 api? The I went to didn't have it

Comment: I followed the link you posted, and found it listed.

Comment: the first linked for the obsolete one should show it but when i did a search for assertequals(int on the second one, nothing turned up